# Navigating to other part of the web page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to navigate from one control to the other in the webpage. Please find the sample code below. When user click on any component on the page he should navigate to other controller.

Sample code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("TabsParentController", function($scope) {
  var setAllInactive = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.workspaces, function(workspace) {
      workspace.active = false;
    });
  };
  $scope.workspaces = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tab1",
    active: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Tab2",
    active: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tab3",
    active: false
  }];
  $scope.addWorkspace = function() {
    setAllInactive();
  };
});
app.controller("TabsChildController", function($scope, $log) {});

function goToNextTab() {
  alert("click");
}
```

Html code:

```
<div ng-controller="TabsParentController">
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces"
             heading="{{workspace.name}}"
             active=workspace.active>
             <div ng-controller="TabsChildController">
               Tab Name: <input type="text" ng-model="workspace.name"/>
            </div>          
        <input type="button" name="clickMe" value="clickMe" onclick="goToNextTab()" class="nexttab"/>

         </tab>
    </tabset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to put the `goToNextTab` function inside the angular scope, then you get the current active workspace index and increment it. So, change the next workspace to active;

```
$scope.goToNextTab = function() {
    var index = 0;
    for (; index < $scope.workspaces.length; index++) {
        if ($scope.workspaces[index].active) {
            $scope.workspaces[index].active = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    index++;
    if (index >= $scope.workspaces.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    $scope.workspaces[index].active = true;
}
```

In the button change `onclick` to `ng-click`.

Plunker update: http://plnkr.co/edit/pYtwQXfTVEufxr2nqzWx?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass your function into the scope and manipulate it to fit your logic, try something like:

> > In HTML

```
<!-- we are passing the object to the click function-->
<input type="button" name="clickMe" value="clickMe" ng-click="goToNextTab(workspace)" class="nexttab"/>
```

> > In JS

```
$scope.goToNextTab = function(getTab){
              // according to you post we want to go to next tab and if we are in last tab we ant to go to first
             // remember this can be any logic
              var goTo = getTab.id===3 ? 1: getTab.id+1;
              // setting the tab active attribute to true 
              var newState = $scope.workspaces.map(function(item){ item.active = item.id===goTo ? true : false; return item;});
              // assigning new vales to workspace scope
             console.log(newState); $scope.workspaces = newState;

            };
```

Working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cHKyMSKnN1wRRKFxsOPa?p=preview